# Is perl removing white spaces when printing the matched capture group?

Tags: regex, perl

There is a large file with this kind of string, among all:

```
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 19:19:47 +0000
```

I am trying to parse out the date like this:

```
if ($msg =~ /(Date:)(.+)(\+0000)/){$date = $2}
```

When I print the string with simple print $date, I get the string output without spaces, like this:

`Sun,30Mar201419:19:47`

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems to work as expected for me, how are you printing the date out?

Comment: Oh I am a dummy. Of course there is a part earlier that strips out the spaces. Sorry.

Comment: There must be something else happening in your code, can you post all of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` should always match spaces, and your case is no exception,

```
my $msg = "Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 19:19:47 +0000";

if ($msg =~ /(Date:)(.+)(\+0000)/) { print "~$2~" }
```

output

```
~ Sun, 30 Mar 2014 19:19:47 ~
```